# Bit copy of encrypted home and other partitions

Tags: home-directory

My laptop is overheating so I need to save all my files before I format the hard drive. I learned how to copy dev/sdX using dd command. However, I am not sure *what* to copy.

Picture from GParted here: http://is.muni.cz/www/256590/fig.png

should I copy sda5 and sda6 only? Or sda2 and sda1? I do not need to use these data on another disk, I just want to be able to access them - therefore I want to put them on external hard drive.

And last question - how I will then mount my encrypted home? Will it work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to take a backup of - just your /home or everything?

Your /home is on /dev/sda6, everything else is on /dev/sda5. We don't know where you've stored what, so if you're unsure copy both of them. If you're absolutely certain everything went into your home folder then backup just /dev/sda6.